# How do I make the background fit the full size of the screen no matter what size the monitor is?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html, css

How do I make the background fit the full size of the screen no matter what size the monitor is?

The main problem I'm having is that I have TWO backgrounds on one page. One on top of the other, so the first upper background isn't filling the full screen at all.

Is this possible to do with two backgrounds?

Here's the CSS, landing-bg2 is the upper bg, and content the lower

```
#content {
    background-color: #eb6e1e;
    position: relative;
    background-position: center top;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    height: auto;
    padding: 160px 0 120px;
    color: #fff;
}
.landing-bg2 {
    background: asset-url("write-bg.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}
```

Comment: I assume you want to toggle between backgrounds, so the top can be swapped with the bottom and vice versa. If yes, since % is relative length you need to set both background on top of base element which has 100% size.

Comment: Also if you could include a JSfiddle of your current code I could take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The browser support for multiple backgrounds is pretty good nowadays, if you wanted 2 full size background images on top of each other you could declare them both in the same div.

Heres the browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multibackgrounds

The syntax is: `background-image:url(''), url('');`

Comma separated. You'll then need to keep the same order in your `background-size:` and `background-position` declarations.